# Uncomment XML in Perl on Windows

Tags: regex, xml, string, perl, replace

I have written a little perl script on Linux to remove a comment from an XML file.

For example, the following command on Linux

```
perl.exe -i -0777 -pe 's/\s*<!--\s*\n(.*?xmlns="abc".*?)\n\s*-->/\n$1/' test.xml
```

uncomments the tag below in `test.xml`

```
...
<!--
<subsystem xmlns="abc"> 
-->
...
```

Now I need to execute the above command on Windows too. I therefore installed Strawberry Perl (Perl v5.30.2), but I can't get the above to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace all `\n` in the LHS with `\R`. You might need to use `"` instead of `'` in the `cmd` window.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by matching the "value" only:  `perl.exe -i -0777 -pe 's/\s*<!--\s*\R(.*abc.*?)\R\s*-->/\n$1/' test.xml`. Unfortunately that is less accurate.

Comment: Try `perl.exe -i -0777 -pe "s/\s*<!--\s*\R(.*?xmlns=\x{22}abc\x{22}.*?)\R\s*-->/\n$1/" test.xml`

Comment: Strangely, it does not work - may it be `\x22` without `{` `}`?

Comment: What about `perl.exe -i -0777 -pe "s/\s*<!--\s*\R(.*?xmlns=""abc"".*?)\R\s*-->/\n$1/" test.xml`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Re "*Replace all `\n` in the LHS with `\R`*", Not gonna help. CRLF is converted to LF on read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of spending hours creating a half-broken solution, use what's already out there!

To remove all comments from an XML doc, you can use

```sh
perl -mXML::LibXML -e'
   binmode($_) for \*STDIN, \*STDOUT;
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*STDIN );
   $_->unbindNode() for $doc->findnodes("//comment()");
   $doc->toFH(\*STDOUT);
' <old.xml >new.xml
```

or

```sh
perl -mXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );
   $_->unbindNode() for $doc->findnodes("//comment()");
   $doc->toFile($ARGV[1]);
' old.xml new.xml
```

Yes, it's a little longer. In addition to the fact that it works and that it's easy to maintain, it won't suddenly break when someone provides

```xml
<message>
   <title>...</title>
   <body><![CDATA[This is not a comment: <!-- ... -->]]></body>
</message>
```

For `cmd`, replace the single quotes with double quotes and vice-versa, and remove the line breaks.

---

You appear to want to remove only specific comments. For that, you can use

```sh
$_->unbindNode() for grep /xmlns="abc"/, $doc->findnodes("//comment()");
```

You can avoid double quotes in regex and double-quoted string literals by using `\x22`. This will help for `cmd`.

```sh
$_->unbindNode() for grep /xmlns=\x22abc\x22/, $doc->findnodes("//comment()");
```

Comment: Oops, you appear to want to remove only specific comments. The beauty of my solution is that it's easy to maintain, including conditions on which comments to remove. Updated my answer.